# Android WebView Zoom to fit Width

Tags: android, webview

I'm calling a webpage that has only a 240px width div.

I can't edit the HTML contents, and the width is always 240px.

**How can I make android webview to ZOOM IN to fit the 240px table in the whole width of the webview?**

I've tested:

`settings.setUseWideViewPort(false);`

and also several combinations of meta viewport, like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=240" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

**How can I force this behaviour?**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it works for me:

```
int default_zoom_level=100;
webview1.setInitialScale(default_zoom_level);
```

or

```
int scale = 100 * webView1.getScale();
webview1.setInitialScale(scale);
```

Hope that helps